# Python27 how to batch read dictionary to execute command

Tags: python, csv, parsing, dictionary

**I just need help with how to work with *X* rows at a time.**

i have a task to parse a 10000 line csv file -> convert it to dictionary -> then process 100 rows at a time making an API call. For this example lets just output to ***print*** function. i will need to execute on every 100 or less as some nested dictionaries will not exactly work out to 100 each, so the code will need to be flexible for this. im using python2.7 with no fancy extra modules like beautiful sup etc. I was given the **api_worker** for loop code block to help me with this task but have no idea how to get it work. Where do i place the print (to be substituted with the api code later)? everything i tried so far prints all, nothing, or every individual string.

*ill cut out a lot of unneeded code:*

```
import *  # assume i have all the right modules

    def parseCSV(filename):
        # this i have working
        return result

    def api_worker(readerObj):
        for majorkey in readerObj.keys():
            listof100 = []
            for idx, line in enumerate(readerObj.get(majorkey)):
                if (idx+1 % 100) != 0:
                    listof100.append(line)
                else:
                    print listof100  #tried here makes no difference
                    del listof100[:]
                    listof100.append(line)
                print listof100  #tried here but outputs all

    def main():
        readerObj = parseCSV('somefile.csv')
        api_worker(readerObj)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

**example source:**

```
{'majorkey1': [{'name':'j','age':'3','height':'6feet'},
 {'name':'r','age':'4','height':'5feet'},
 {'name':'o','age':'5','height':'3feet'}],
 'majorkey2':[{'name':'n','age':'6','height':'4feet'},
 {'name':'s','age':'7','height':'7feet'},
 {'name':'q','age':'7','height':'8feet'}]}
```

**desired output:**

if using this small sample, and i want to print 2 rows at a time the desired output from **print** would be:

**from majorkey1 group**

```
{'name':'j','age':'3','height':'6feet'}{'name':'r','age':'4','height':'5feet'}
```

*sleep 1 second...*

```
{'name':'o','age':'5','height':'3feet'}
```

**from majorkey2 group**

*sleep 1 second...*

```
{'name':'n','age':'6','height':'4feet'}{'name':'s','age':'7','height':'7feet'}
```

*sleep 1 second...*

```
{'name':'q','age':'7','height':'8feet'}
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility:

```
from itertools import islice

d = {
        'majorkey1': [
            { 'name':'j','age':'3','height':'6feet' },
            { 'name':'r','age':'4','height':'5feet' },
            { 'name':'o','age':'5','height':'3feet' },
        ],
        'majorkey2': [
            { 'name':'n','age':'6','height':'4feet' },
            { 'name':'s','age':'7','height':'7feet' },
            { 'name':'q','age':'7','height':'8feet' },
        ],
}

n = 2

for k, v in d.items():
    print '{}:'.format(k)
    it = iter(v)
    while True:
        rows = list(islice(it, n))
        if len(rows) == 0:
            break
        print '\t{}'.format(rows)

# Output:
# majorkey1:
#   [{'age': '3', 'name': 'j', 'height': '6feet'}, {'age': '4', 'name': 'r', 'height': '5feet'}]
#   [{'age': '5', 'name': 'o', 'height': '3feet'}]
# majorkey2:
#   [{'age': '6', 'name': 'n', 'height': '4feet'}, {'age': '7', 'name': 's', 'height': '7feet'}]
#   [{'age': '7', 'name': 'q', 'height': '8feet'}]
```

(BTW, if you really want the format you gave above, you could replace that list `print` with `print ''.join(map(repr, rows))`, and of course you could insert a sleep wherever you want.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to break up a list into fixed-length chunks, without loading the whole list into memory? This is possible using some help from the `itertools` module. This is taken from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: thanks for this. I agree with not loading the entire list to memory as the file ill use will be huge. Ill play around with this to wrap my head around it. thanks!